# Does $(x-y)^{2n} \le (x+y)^{2n}$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

I want to prove that, for $x, y \ge 0$, one has:
$$(x-y)^{2n} \le (x+y)^{2n}$$
for every $n = 0,1,2,...$. If $n=0$ the result is trivial. My proof goes like this. First, notice that:
$$(x-y)^{2} = x^{2}-2xy+y^{2} \le x^{2}+2xy +y^{2} = (x+y)^{2} $$
and because $f(x) = x^{n}$ is an increasing function of $x$, the result follows.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: That is correct. What are your doubts about it?

Comment: Just the last step, I wasn't completely sure about it. Thanks!

Comment: If you are having doubts on the last step, maybe make it a little bit more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x,y\geq 0$, one has $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|=(x+y)$. Hence
$$(x-y)^2=|x-y|^2\leq (x+y)^2$$
The function $y\to y^n$ being increasing for $n>0$, the desired inequality follows.